# Windows-XP ODBC Administration not found

Tags: windows-xp, odbc

In Windows XP and 7 it is possible to administrate the odbc connections through an odbc-adminstrator-utility. The odbc-administrator can be reached with settings/control panel/.
After a new setup of my WindowsXP computer the odbc-administrator seems to be disappeared. Does anyone have an idea what happend and how can I find or reinstall the odbc-administrator?

Thanks for any help.
giordano

Comment: Could you check if the file odbccad32.exe is present in your Windows\System32 folder? This is the executable of the ODBC administrator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

Start Menu->execute (or Win+r for keyb shortcut)

then write:

```
odbccp32.cpl
```

and hit `Enter`